# Generic.xaml binding to a objectDataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't exactly know what the problem is since I am almost sure I did what other posts told me to do. I have bound a observablecollection of strings to a comboBox before so it should work.

dataClass:

```
namespace UIBlocksLib.Data_VM__classes
{
  public class BlockController : INotify, IStatementCollection
   {
      private List<UIStackBlock> _mUIStackBlocks = new List<UIStackBlock>();
      public ObservableCollection<string> _mUIVariables = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "VariableA", "VariableB", "VariableC" };

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public ObservableCollection<string> getVariables
      {
         get
         {
            return _mUIVariables;
         }
         set
         {
            _mUIVariables = value;
            onPropertyChanged("_mUIVariables");
         }
      }

      public BlockController()
      {
      }
      public void addVariable(string aVariableName)
      {
         _mUIVariables.Add(aVariableName);
         onPropertyChanged("_mUIVariables");
      }

      public void addUIStackBlock(UIStackBlock aUIStackBlock)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public void onPropertyChanged(string aPropertyName)
      {
         PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(aPropertyName));
      }

      public void removeStackBlockByIndex(int aIndex)
      {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
       }
    }
```

my objectDataProvider in my generic.xaml

```
 <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataObject"
                             ObjectType="{x:Type dataClass:BlockController}"
                             MethodName="getVariables">
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

and my style which is bound to my class

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UISet}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type local:UISet}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Fill="#AD2B27" ClipToBounds="True"/>
                        <ComboBox DataContext="{staticResource dataObject}" Background="#FFEE4A4A" x:Name="comboBox" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="70" Margin="5, 23" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

also tried making the context static/ not using a context/ using the name of the variable. the compiler does recognize the getVariables when looking through the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Code getVariables is not a method but a property. This way it should work:

```
 <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataObject"
                             ObjectType="{x:Type dataClass:BlockController}"
                             MethodName="GetVariables">
    </ObjectDataProvider>

public ObservableCollection<string> GetVariables()
        {
            return getVariables;
        }
```

Comment: Eugh, I really don't know how I didn't notice that. Thanks, it worked just fine.